# Colon " : " doesnt appear in my timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

How do I make my colon punctuation appear between my minutes and seconds? Two hours on this and still doesn't work.  It is a pretty stupid question but still.
I want to my timer look like this " 02:00 " but instead it just look like this " 02 00 " how can I fix that?

```js
// set minutes
var mins = 2;
var down = true;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a                 different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
var timeout;
var doispontos = ":";

countdown();

function countdown() {
  timeout = setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
}

function colorchange(minutes, seconds) {
  if (minutes.value == "00" && seconds.value == "59") {
    minutes.style.color = "orange";
    seconds.style.color = "orange";
    doispontos = "orange";

  } else if (minutes.value == "00" && seconds.value == "30") {
    minutes.style.color = "red";
    seconds.style.color = "red";
    doispontos = "red";
  }

}

function Decrement() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining

    if (seconds < 59) {
      seconds.value = secs;

    } else {
      minutes.value = getminutes();
      seconds.value = getseconds();
    }
    colorchange(minutes, seconds);

    secs--;
    if (secs < 0) {
      secs--;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      return;
    }
    countdown();
  }
}

function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
}

function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -5%;">
  <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -40%;">
</div>
```

Comment: you don't add it anywhere?

Comment: You need to type it between the two `<input>` elements? You seem to be using a variable `doispontos` that you initialise to `":"` then change to `"orange"` or `"red"` but don't really seem to be using at all...

Comment: I tried typing it between the two <input> elements but it has one problem, I can't change the size of it or at least I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using inline styling with fixed positioning. So anything you add that you want between them would need to have similar styling. For instance using a `span` tag:

```
<div id="timer">
  <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -5%;">
  <span style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -30%;">:</span>
  <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -40%;">
</div>
```

```js
// set minutes
var mins = 2;
var down = true;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a                 different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
var timeout;
var doispontos = ":";

countdown();

function countdown() {
  timeout = setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
}

function colorchange(minutes, seconds) {
  if (minutes.value == "00" && seconds.value == "59") {
    minutes.style.color = "orange";
    seconds.style.color = "orange";
    doispontos = "orange";

  } else if (minutes.value == "00" && seconds.value == "30") {
    minutes.style.color = "red";
    seconds.style.color = "red";
    doispontos = "red";
  }

}

function Decrement() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining

    if (seconds < 59) {
      seconds.value = secs;

    } else {
      minutes.value = getminutes();
      seconds.value = getseconds();
    }
    colorchange(minutes, seconds);

    secs--;
    if (secs < 0) {
      secs--;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      return;
    }
    countdown();
  }
}

function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
}

function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -5%;">
  <span style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -30%;">:</span>
  <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -40%;">
</div>
```

Alternatively you could simplify the HTML by moving the CSS to either the `HEAD` 
tag or into a separate file. Also, there really is no need to use an `input` here as you are simply displaying text.

```
<div id="timer">
  <span id="minutes"></span>
  <span>:</span>
  <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

```js
// set minutes
var mins = 2;
var down = true;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a                 different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
var timeout;
var doispontos = ":";

countdown();

function countdown() {
  timeout = setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
}

function colorchange(minutes, seconds) {
  if (minutes.innerText == "00" && seconds.innerText == "59") {
    minutes.style.color = "orange";
    seconds.style.color = "orange";
    doispontos = "orange";

  } else if (minutes.innerText == "00" && seconds.innerText == "30") {
    minutes.style.color = "red";
    seconds.style.color = "red";
    doispontos = "red";
  }

}

function Decrement() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining

    if (seconds < 59) {
      seconds.innerText = secs;

    } else {
      minutes.innerText = getminutes();
      seconds.innerText = getseconds();
    }
    colorchange(minutes, seconds);

    secs--;
    if (secs < 0) {
      secs--;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      return;
    }
    countdown();
  }
}

function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
}

function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
}
```

```css
#timer {
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  background-color: none;
  font-size: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: -5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <span id="minutes"></span>
  <span>:</span>
  <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and how do I make it change the color when it reaches a  certain point along with the timer

Comment: The colon? The same as you have done for the minutes and seconds. Or in the second example you could change the font color for the entire div. Also, there are a lot of simplifications you can make in your JS code as well. It would make a great exercise working on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/tpLg3osL/

i just added it inside a `<span>` tag

Comment: Thanks there are now two possible anwers cause they both work